# printing bytes read from binary file at a certain file position C

Tags: c, io, fopen, fread

I am trying to print a fixed number of bytes  (128) at at fixed file position (256) from a binary file to the screen.
However, the results show up look like:

[image: output screenshot]

For reference, I don't really know what's in the binary file; but I suspect that it's not squares.

Code is here:

```
int main() 
{
   FILE *file;
   char *buffer;

   file = fopen ( "binaryfile.bin" , "rb" );
   if (file==NULL) 
   {
       fputs ("Couldn' open file",stderr);
       exit (-1);
   }

    fseek (file , 0 , 256);
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*128);
    fread (buffer,128,1,file);
    fwrite (buffer , sizeof(char)*128, 1, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect printable characters in a binary file? There are no squares in a file, only numbers which make sense in context. You can check their values by printing them in a loop, or with a file dump utility. Some text editors allow you to view the raw file bytes too, in hexadecimal format.

Comment: This will probably be garbage because you are getting random control characters and upper-half characters which depend on your the terminal's character set. Are you wanting a hex editor?

Comment: You're actually using `fwrite` very strangely - it's got *separate arguments* from element size and number of elements, yet you multiply both into one... (and sizeof(char) is always 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how to read 128 bytes from a binary file and print each byte as a 2-digit hexadecimal value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char *buffer;
    file = fopen("binaryfile.bin", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Could not open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(file, 256, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 128);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 128, file);
    for (int index = 0; index < 128; index++) {
        printf("%02X", ((unsigned int) buffer[index]) & 0x0FF);
        if (index % 8 == 7) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Output**

```
AD 0D 25 C8 74 AD D3 13
D5 00 62 EC CF 73 8E A4
61 2E 31 2F 70 ED D3 14
03 CC 06 B6 FB 77 FB ED
B4 0A 59 5F 50 00 61 59
D6 0B 21 F2 E6 1B 1A 07
DF 5E B8 32 17 D5 3E 29
0D 9E AE 47 D7 AF 86 4F
1E 75 6F EA C7 F7 A3 82
56 41 AA E8 02 42 91 D6
08 34 4F 63 40 9B 9C 06
0A 4E 65 30 90 7D 8A 4B
33 D1 50 9A 99 C5 F3 34
D9 A6 E0 2C 33 76 B3 DD
69 DF F9 30 8C 37 3A 51
9A 4F DB 81 81 F7 F5 F9
```

**Note**

This program is missing some error checking and does not free allocated memory. This code should not be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 3):

`fseek (file , 0 , 256);` is wrong. The third argument to `fseek` is supposed to be one of `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR` or `SEEK_END`; the *second* is the offset. To set the file pointer to the 256th byte in the file, use:

```
fseek(file, 256, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: And how is this going to make the squares go away? :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If the file is in fact binary, it probably won't. But now OP's `fread` call will in fact read 128 bytes starting at position 256 like they wanted.

Comment: That is true, yes.

Comment: Also, fread() is being used improperly. It should be `int n = fread(buffer,1,128,file);` The second parameter is the size of each element; the third is the number of elements to read.Then n will be the number of bytes actually read.